# Check if string contains any keywords that exists in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to filter some content based on which keyword exists in an array, but not sure how to do that, tried using `includes`, `indexof` , and `search` functions, but it didn't work in my case.

My first attempt:

```
const filters = ['movie', 'food']
contents
 .filter( content => filters.includes(content.name))
```

the problem is that `content.name` is a string with multiple words eg "watch your favourite movie", "vote for your favourite food", etc. and I want to check if a string includes one of the keywords in filters variable. Currently `includes()` returns `false` because it's trying to match the exact string.

Comment: Use a regular expression on the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check each word in `filters` against each `content.name`. You can do that with `.some()` which will return `true` (and halt the search early) when a match is found.

```
const filters = ['movie', 'food']
const result = contents.filter(content => 
  filters.some(s => content.name.includes(s))
)
```

Note that `.includes()` will match subsections of words. You need to establish word boundaries, perhaps with a regex, to get a whole word match.

You can do this by creating an array of regexes instead of strings, and using the `.test()` method of the regex.

```
const filters = [/\bmovie\b/, /\bfood\b/]
const result = contents.filter(content => 
  filters.some(re => re.test(content.name))
)
```

Add the `i` modifier to each regex if it should be a case insensitive match.

Or instead of an array of regex, you can use a single regex.

```
const filters = /\b(?:movie|food)\b/
const result = contents.filter(content => filters.test(content.name))
```

Comment: Trying to answer this question I've just learned how to use the `some` method hehehe :-).